# resize function firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

Im using the resize() method to run a function the will return on 
  varied viewport sizes like 992,768, ect. problem is that the 
  function is executing everytime causing a glitch in the DOM. example 
  in codepen https://codepen.io/paul-solomon/pen/WBEgQe

```
//javascript

$(window).resize(function(){
nh_masonry.data.loadorder();
});


//css

.masonry_grid_quarter__container{
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 column-count:3;
 column-gap:8px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px){
.masonry_grid_quarter__container{
 column-count:2;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 .masonry_grid_quarter__container{
  column-count:2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:580px){
 .masonry_grid_quarter__container{
  column-count:1;
  }
 }
```

expected result: resize function executes at specific viewports
actual result: executes resize multiple times creating a DOM glitch.

Comment: Hi Paul, any luck on getting this to work?

Comment: I haven't .had any luck with that. when console.log(), it seems to add the object multiple time while resizing the browser window width, any other suggestions?

Comment: Paul, I'm looking at your codepen right now, what you can do is have a variable that keeps track of the current state of the viewport, let me right something up for you.

Comment: Hi Paul, try out my solution below. I've also updated your codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable that keeps track of the current-state of the DOM.

Let's create a variable called `currentViewPort` that can have a value of "desktop", "tablet" or "mobile".

When the window resizes, we will toggle the value of `currentViewPort`. If `currentViewPort` is already matching our screen-layout, then we will not call the function again. It will only be called when we enter a different layout.

Here it is in action: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaGboG?editors=1111

```
   var App = (function ($) {

   var nh_masonry = {};
   var currentViewPort = ""
   //sets initial reorder variable
   nh_masonry.vars = { reorder : false} 

   nh_masonry.onload = function () {
            // when the document is loaded sets the reorder variable to true
            // and also loads the order object method 
            nh_masonry.vars.reorder = !nh_masonry.vars.reorder;
            nh_masonry.data.loadorder();

     $(window).resize(function(){
           // re-set layout after resize
           if($( window ).width() <= 992 && $( window ).width() > 768 && currentViewPort !== "desktop"){

             currentViewPort = "desktop"
             console.log("desktop");
              nh_masonry.data.loadorder();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.tablet();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.mobile();

           } else if ($( window ).width() == 768 && currentViewPort !== "tablet"){

             currentViewPort = "tablet"
             console.log("tablet");
              nh_masonry.data.loadorder();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.tablet();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.mobile();

           } else if ($( window ).width() < 768 && $( window ).width() >= 380 && currentViewPort !== "mobile"){
            currentViewPort = "mobile"
             console.log("mobile");
              nh_masonry.data.loadorder();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.tablet();
              // nh_masonry.responsive.mobile();
           }
         })  
     };
```

Comment: I would suggest using else if, that way one does not need to read trough all of it to see if multiple can happen

Comment: that  variable does solve the multiple firing issue, however one last question is does codepen render the DOM event resize correct, noticing that I have to refresh to see the correct left to right load order for responsive view - Christopher Ngo

Comment: @PaulSolomon I dont think codepen does a good job of showing the DOM event resize. Whenever your resize the codepen browser it tries to do its own thing on top of what we had written. Try it on your local project and it should be as expected.